# Sql Server - display a second record below first one with other data

Tags: sql-server

I have an sql table with the below data:

```
Id   department     Amount
1      Accounting   10000
2      Catering      5000
3      Cleaning      5000
```

I want to return the data as below:

```
Id   department      Amount
1    Accounting      10000
1       50%
2     Catering       5000
2       25%     
3     Cleaning       5000
3       25%
```

This implies every records return a second record just below it and display the percentage of the total amount. I have tried to use a PIVOT table but still I cannot position
the second row just below the first related one.

Has anyone ever done something similar I need just some guidelines.

Comment: use Union then order by ID

Comment: Why below? In your example the column you are outputting the percentage in is the `Department` column, so having a percentage in it as well as a textual value doesn't make any sense. It would make more sense to add a calculated column after the `Amount` column. For instance: `SELECT Id, department, Amount, (Amount / 20000) * 100 AS [Percentage] FROM [myTable]`

Comment: @GulamHusainAnsari UNION requires that all result sets have the same number of columns with compatible metadata (data types)

Comment: @Pred , One set will contain department info, second will contain % info, Yes you are right for this you have to change the datatype to same datatype, then union then order by ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #T(Id int, Dept varchar(10),Amount int)
insert into #T
values(1,'Accounting',10000),(2,'Catering',5000),(3,'Cleaning',5000)


declare @Totll float = (Select sum(Amount) from #T)

Select *
from #T
union
select Id,Convert(varchar(50), (Amount/@Totll)*100)+'%',0
from #T
order by Id,Amount desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to calculate the total of the amounts.
Then use `UNION ALL` for your table and the query which calculates the percentages:

```
with cte as (select sum(amount) sumamount from tablename)
select id, department, amount 
from tablename
union all
select id, concat(100 * amount / (select sumamount from cte), '%'), null 
from tablename 
order by id, amount desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=178a435b2b3d59c93b127ef69c7ff4bc).
Results:

```
> id | department | amount
> -: | :--------- | -----:
>  1 | Accounting |  10000
>  1 | 50%        |   null
>  2 | Catering   |   5000
>  2 | 25%        |   null
>  3 | Cleaning   |   5000
>  3 | 25%        |   null
```